# Make a key behave as another key

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, elisp

I want certain keys and key combinations to behave as other keys or key combinations in Emacs. For example, I want <kbd>F5</kbd> to behave as a substitute for <kbd>C-c</kbd> for every possible combination involving it, or <kbd>C-S-</kbd> as <kbd>C-</kbd>. Is it possible to do that without manually rebinding all such key combinations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The keys you are referring to are known as 'prefix keys'. A prefix key has its own keymap, so to make another key behave the same, you need to assign it to the same keymap. For control-c, you use the `mode-specific-map`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") mode-specific-map)
```

Control on its own isn't a prefix key, or really a key at all, since it doesn't send a keypress *to Emacs*[1] until you hit another key. I'm not sure how to remap C-S- to C- within Emacs. You could do it system-wide with xmodmap, but that's probably not what you want.

[1] the control key (and shift, alt) do send a keypress to the operating system, but Emacs doesn't 'see' this unless there's another key pressed at the same time

Comment: +1 but...  *"Control on its own isn't a prefix key, or really a key at all, since it doesn't send a keypress"*...  Control definitely does send a keypress by itself.  You can use, say, *xev* under Linux to see that.  It sends both a keypress when you press it and a keyrelease when you release it.  A *xev* output for CTRL on my system gives: *KeyPress eventKeyPress event... state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L)...* etc.  I kinda dispute that you wrote that control isn't "really a key at all".  My keyboard's CTRL and CAPS-LOCK remapped to act as CTRL do take offense ; )

Comment: @TacticalCoder: Fair point, as far as X is concerned. But I don't think the keypress registered by X is visible to Emacs on its own. There isn't anyway for Emacs to detect or respond to a modifier key if it isn't modifying another key. So from Emacs' perspective, CTRL on its own isn't a key until it is combined with another key.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer

```
(define-key key-translation-map [f5] (kbd "\C-c"))
```

Here is a [good resource](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_key-translation-map.html).

To summarize the link given above: The disadvantage of global-set-key is that, when you define a key combination to enter a symbol, it doesn't work in isearch.

key-translation-map also has a problem. Imagine you defined a symbol <kbd>|</kbd> to execute a command and <kbd>C-|</kbd> to enter the symbol <kbd>|</kbd>, pressing <kbd>C-|</kbd> will execute the command.

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work well with prefix commands. For instance, `C-x 8 m` generates the micro sign "µ". But if `key-translation-map` is used to remap `|` to `C-x`, the sequence `| 8 m` yields `C-x 8 m is undefined` instead of the micro sign.